# SQL Server: what does leaf_offset column mean in sys.system_internals_partition_columns view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run:

```
select c.column_id, c.Name, ipc.* 
from sys.system_internals_partition_columns ipc 
join sys.partitions p 
    on pc.partition_id = p.partition_id 
join sys.columns c 
    on c.column_id = pc.partition_column_id 
    and c.object_id = p.object_id 
where p.object_id = object_id(N'TABLE_NAME') 
order by c.column_id;
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Could you please explain why leaf_offset has a -1, -2 and -3 value for the last 3 columns?

[Here](http://improve.dk/exploring-the-sys-system_internals_partition_columns-ti-field/) I found some info about sys.system_internals_partition_columns, but it was not enough to understand. Note: there is no NULL value for the c.Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative value for the leaf_offset means that the column is a variable-length column. A value of -1 indicates that column 7 is the first variable-length. -2 indicates column 8 is the second variable-length column. Likewise, -3 indicates that column 9 is the third variable-length column.